# Example of a function in Sobolev-Slobodeskji space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

How do i show that $u(r,\theta) = r^\lambda sin(\lambda \theta)$ belongs to $H^{1+\lambda}(\Omega),$ with $\lambda \in (0,1)$ for $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: $\Omega$ is probably an open set containing the origin.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yes.